# Agrupando apenas pelo primeiro item do ManyToMany no Django

Tags: django, annotation

Eu tenho duas tabelas: Author e Book

onde Book tem um author = `ManyToManyField`

Reparem nos exemplos com A1 (autor um) e L1 (livro um), assim por diante.

```
Author - Book
A1 - L1, L2, L3
A2 - L1
A1 - L3
A1 - L1
A1 - L1
A2 - L2, L3
A1 - L3
```

Eu preciso fazer um agrupamento pegando apenas o primeiro livro do M2M. E retornar a seguinte contagem:

```
Books
L1 = 4
L2 = 1
L3 = 2
```

**Total: 7**

Eu tentei

```
Author.objects.values('book').annotate(quant=Count('book')).order_by('book').values('book', 'quant')
```

Mas ele me retorna uma quantidade maior de livros, visto que ele conta todos os livros da relação M2M.

Como eu faço para pegar somente um livro de cada iteração, para retornar o resultado desejado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido.

```
def books_list(self):
    count = {}
    for item in Author.objects.all():
        first_book = item.books.first()
        if first_book:
            count[first_book] = count.get(first_book, 0) + 1
    return count
```